# how to send params in angular to server side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, controller

I would like to send a param from my html - to server side and to find a query in mLab by this param.
so I sent in my url:

```
http://localhost:8080/getStudentById.html?idStudent=1
```

and my controller looks like that:

```
     var showidApp = angular.module('showidApp',['ngRoute']) 
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // configure the routing rules here
        $routeProvider.when('/getStusdentById.html', {
            controller: 'studentidCtrl'
        });
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })

showidApp.controller('studentidCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$routeParams',function($scope,$http, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams.idStudent);
     $http.get("http://localhost:3000/getbyid/"+ $routeParams.idStudent).success(function(data){
        $scope.studById = data; 
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

so in my server side I have a path getbyid/:id that works and I can see the data by an id that is sent in the url
I get on my console on my client side - undefined

I got little confused with connecting the two.
thanks for the help :)

Comment: use param's part of $http... `$http.get(url, params)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple request params its better to use property id for each params ex: stuentId, schoolId

Below is the sample code.

```js
var requestParams = {
  studentId : '1',
  schoolId : '2'
}

$http({
  url : 'http://localhost:3000/getbyid/',
  method: 'GET',
  params: requestParams
})
.success(function(data) {
  callBackFunc(data);
})
.error(function(err){
  console.log('Error: ',err);
});
```

At server side you will receive request parameter object and use the params with the corresponding property id

Comment: I have only one param - by student id I guess I really messed it up

Comment: so I need routeParams?

Answer (score 0):

Your route definition should like this, since idStudent is not a url parameter. It is a query parameter which will be automatically available in $routeParams.

`$routeProvider.when('/getStudentById.html', {`

Controller:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/getbyid/" + $routeParams.idStud).success(function(data){
```

since your query param name is idStud in http://localhost:8080/getStudentById.html?idStud=1

Comment: on the server side its writes me a mongoError that I don't understand why because when I checked it on the sever side and its all good, I see the json